# LinQ to view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

In my controller I have a method that looks like this:

```
   var CarModelAndGear = from search in entity.CarsCategories
                                   where search.ID == CarCategoryId[0]
                                   select new { search.Manufacturer, search.Model, search.Gear };
```

I'm trying to get the output of this statement to the view..

```
ViewData["somename"] = CarModelAndGear;
```

This way won't work.. I'm getting an error "LINQ to entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. "
How can I get 'CarModelAndGear' to the view?

Comment: This way won't work... describe your problem and not use general statement for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the category in a variable first because the provider is not able to interpret the list indexer method:

```
int CatId = CarCategoryId[0];
var CarModelAndGear = from search in entity.CarsCategories
                      where search.ID == CatId 
                      select new { search.Manufacturer, search.Model, search.Gear };
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model for your result

```
public class CarViewResult
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Gear { get; set; }

    public CarViewResult(string manufacturer, string model, string gear)
    {
        this.Manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.Model = model;
        this.Gear = gear;
    }
}
```

Add add the new model to your LINQ query

```
var CarModelAndGear = from search in entity.CarsCategories
                      where search.ID == CarCategoryId[0]
                      select new CarViewResult(search.Manufacturer, search.Model, search.Gear);

ViewData["somename"] = CarModelAndGear.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using LinqToSql here. So what it is trying to do is convert that Linq expression into a SQL statement.

While you can access an item in a collection from C#, this cannot be translated into SQL, so it falls over.

Try this rather:

```
var id = CarCategoryId[0];
var CarModelAndGear = from search in entity.CarsCategories
                                   where search.ID == id 
                                   select new { search.Manufacturer, search.Model, search.Gear };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute linq and then assign to ViewData

```
ViewData["somename"] = CarModelAndGear.ToList();
```

But i prefer approach described by live2, when you will combine everything to model and then pass the model